perf error: sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 4 (Interrupted system call) for event
When I run the following perf command I get the error:
sudo perf record -e python:take_gil -- python3-dbg -c "import time; time.sleep(1)"
Error:
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 4 (Interrupted system call) for event (python:take_gil).
/bin/dmesg | grep -i perf may provide additional information.

The command /bin/dmesg | grep -i perf
[    0.541086] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 154 no PMU driver, software events only.
[    0.541759] NMI watchdog: Perf NMI watchdog permanently disabled
[  306.244607] audit: type=1400 audit(1718119926.884:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1803 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  311.952219] audit: type=1400 audit(1718119932.599:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2509 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"

I don't know how or where to begin figuring out this problem.
